# Recyclerview height is as big as screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm

Guys I have a simple recyclerview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/realm_recycler_view"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it is not displaying as it should. I am expecting it to show like a normal list view ( height wise ) but somehow it takes the whole screen per recyclerview item. ( so its as big as the screen )

I have tried both wrap_content and match_parent without success..

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_fragment_two, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);

    setupRecyclerView();
    return rootView;
}

public void setupRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new gradeRealmAdapter(this, realm.where(Grade.class).findAllAsync()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need that `weightSum="1"` attribute spec on the layout. Can you try without it?

Comment: Nope that didn't help @milosmns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us the layout of list element. It looks like you have `match_parent` in your element layout height. Please, post also your RecyclerView item layout.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got enough reputation points to add comments.

Comment: That was the trick! The list element was set on match_parent on its height instead of wrap_content. Thanks very much